# Как создать hash строку адреса файла?

Tags: php

Как сформировать хэш строку, которая состояла бы из URL-адреса файла, который в свою очередь лежит на сервере?
То есть например у меня есть файл Hash, который лежит по адресу http://localhost/project/hash/ 
Так как данный адрес преобразовать в хэш строку.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Но непонятный.

Comment: @Ипатьев немного дополнил вопрос

Comment: Если вы знаете путь к файлу, то просто через функцию hash http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash.php

Comment: `$hash = md5('http://localhost/project/hash/');`. Это единственное что можно ответить на такой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Криптографических функций хэширования очень много. Вы можете воспользоваться популярными хэш-функциями md5(), sha1() или crc32(), которые в качестве параметра принимают строку, которую нужно захешировать. Во многом все зависит от задачи, требований к коллизиям, безопасности хэша, скорости. Более подробная информация по многим хэш-функциям есть в [данной](http://rhash.anz.ru/hashes.php?l=ru) статье. На PHP.net так же есть [статья](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php), которая описывает основные принципы хэширования паролей.

```
$hashString = sha1($text);
```

Не используйте md5(), sha1() их для хеширования паролей! Из-за той скорости, с которой современные компьютеры могут "обратить" эти хэширующие алгоритмы, многие профессионалы компьютерной безопасности строго не рекомендуют использовать их для хэширования паролей.

Comment: Без разницы чем хэшировать пароли, так как если у вас увели базу данных, то ни какие хэши вам уже не помогут!

Comment: @Visman ошибочное мнение. Я увожу часть базы данных платежной системы, но доступа к внутренним сервисам у меня нет, я предположим выкачал ее через какой-нибудь метод получения пользователя, где программист засветил hash пользователя случайно и использует обычный md5. Теперь, я могу разгадать какие-то хеши по существующим базам и скомпроментировать действия пользователя, например перевод средств на свою карточку, и я могу сделать это очень быстро. Используя безопасный хэш со стоимостью вычисления, неизвестно сколько я буду разгадывать один пароль и разгадаю ли его вообще.